# du -sk size difference on different environments

Tags: bash, centos7, gnu-coreutils, du

I am getting two different outputs for blank file created in two different environments. On Centos 7 with GNU Coreutils 8.22 (du --v optput)

```
$touch tempfile
$du -sk tempfile
 4    tempfile
```

is the output. When I try it on different CentOS7 GNU Coreutils 8.22 i get

```
$touch tempfile
$du -sk tempfile
 0    tempfile
```

Please help I need to know what is making it act differently.

Comment: `GNU diskutils`? I for once, can't even find it in Google search, are you sure its the right name?

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62049/37612

Comment: @jm666: I am starting to doubt, if `GNU diskutils` even exist?, google can't find it :)

Comment: sorry its coreutils..

Comment: @jm666 I understand that part with metadata. but if you check the same file with ls -lh gives 0 whereas any directory which has metadata of files containing in it has 4K as pointed out in  unix.stackexchange.com/q/62049/37612.

Comment: This could be a difference in the type of filesystem in the two environments...

Comment: @twalberg Like the cylinders etc or type like ext4 xfs? In either case I will check tomorrow and update